# Closed form solution for $U$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Given one optimization objective：
$$
\min\limits_{U}||U^TX-Y||_F^2+\lambda tr(U^TQU)\quad s.t. U^T\Sigma U=aI
$$
Where $X,Y,\Sigma$ are all known matrixs, $\lambda,a$ are constants, $Q$ is a symmetric matrix, $I$ is an identity matrix, introducing lagrange multiplier matrix $\Lambda$(a diagonal matrix), we can get Lagrangian function $L$:
$$
L=tr((U^TX-Y)^T(U^TX-Y))+\lambda tr(U^TQU)+tr(\Lambda^T(aI-U^T\Sigma U))
$$
It's derivative is $\frac{\partial L}{\partial U}=(XX^T+XX^T)U-XY^T-XY^T+\lambda(QU+Q^TU)-2\Sigma U\Lambda=2XX^TU-2XY^T+2\lambda QU-2\Sigma U\Lambda$

make $\frac{\partial L}{\partial U}=0$, so $(XX^T+\lambda Q)U=XY^T+\Sigma U\Lambda$

But how to calculate $U$? and is it right? Please help me, thank you very much!

**Exact Problem:** Does there exist a closed-form solution for $U$ satisfying $(XX^T+\lambda Q)U=XY^T+\Sigma U\Lambda$?

Comment: Why do you have trace in Lagrangian for the multipliers?. $aI$ is a matrix.

Comment: Well $\Theta$ should be the Lagrangian multiplier matrix, and then I have a matrix inner product $<\Theta,aI-U^T\Sigma U>=tr(\Theta^T(aI-U^T\Sigma U))$ in my lagrangian function, in fact I only concern about contraints that $U_i^T\Sigma_{ii}U_i=a$, where $\Sigma$ is also a diagonal matrix, so $\Theta$ should be a diagonal matrix ($\Lambda$)

Comment: Oh okay, I see so $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: This migh be a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) which is solvable through vectorization